# Having trouble getting C# code to stack a tower. How can I modify this to get it working more like Jenga?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am trying to build a stacking tower in Unity3D, with levels that change direction each time a new level is added. So far, I've gotten it partially working - on odd numbers, the directions switch, but I can't get the offset correct. This results in a tower that tends to explode.

```
void buildTower() {

    int counter = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < gridY; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++) {
            Vector3 pos;
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.identity;

            Vector3 rotEuler;

            //rotEuler = new Vector3(270, 0, 0);
            //pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0) * spacing;

            if (y % 2 != 0) {
                rotEuler = new Vector3(270, 0, 0);
                pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0) * spacing;
            } else {
                rotEuler = new Vector3(270, 270, 0);
                pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0) * spacing;
            }

            rot.eulerAngles = rotEuler;

            GameObject plank = Instantiate(plankObject) as GameObject;

            plank.transform.parent = Tower.transform;

            plankObject.transform.rotation = rot;
            plankObject.transform.position = pos;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your spacing variable needs to just be a tiny bit bigger than the height of your blocks and that should help it fit together well.

Comment: Doesn't there still need to be an offset on posistion from zero when the planks are turned?

Comment: Yes, on the yaw axis , ideally your prefab position should be oriented from the centre of your block pile